# Why won't my UV Editing Textures show up in Texture Paint?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

I have done other Blender projects before this one but for some reason, after I go into editing and unwrap my object, the outline of the UV Wrap will not show up in Texture Paint. I'm using 3.0 of Blender and I have selected all of the values. No other outlines are showing up for the UV unwrap on my other shapes.[image: Picture of the UV Unwrap showing all of the outlines][image: Texture paint where none of the correct outlines are being shown]

Comment: Are you meaning you expect the UVs to show in the 2D Image Editor on your left when in TexPaint mode? Or do you mean you want to see the wireframe while painting in the 3d view on the right?

Comment: I don’t think the outlines for the other objects are supposed to show in texture paint, even if it’s the same texture, because it’s not the same mesh object. Is this what you’re expecting?

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe this will help - 'Display Texture paint UVs' must have accidentally gotten unchecked in the view menu in the 2d editor in your case.
See below
[image]